# "Syntax Error" in Hopper Disassembler while assembling instruction

Tags: disassembly, hopper

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://dhiyaneshgeek.github.io/mobile/security/2021/12/25/hopper-disassembler/ which shows how to bypass the jailbreak detection in a sample demo app named "SecureStoreV1.ipa".

The idea is to break the `tbz` (test bit and branch if zero) ARM instruction and convert it into `tbnz' (test bit and branch if not zero).

Having a paid version of hopper, it allows me to directly change the instruction via GUI but while doing so, it gives me a syntax error. Attaching screenshot for reference.

[image]

Can anyone help me here please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the other options in that CPU Mode dropdown?  I suspect that "ARM" refers to the original 32-bit architecture, which didn't have TBZ/TBNZ instructions - you'd have to select a 64-bit option.

Comment: There are two options - ARM/Thumb. Tried selecting Thumb as well but syntax error still stays.

Comment: As a workaround, I just tried using `cbnz` with checking register x0. It worked fine. But I am curious to know why am I getting that syntax error for tbnz.